# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `items[0]` of type `string` supplied to `ImageGallery`, expected `object`

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, state, image-gallery

I know this probably seems trivial, but I am a newbie and I am obviously missing something.

I am trying to create an array of what appear to be JSON objects to pass to react-image-gallery. See here [NPM react-image-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery)

According to that web page, I need to do something like:

```
const images = [
  {
    original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/',
    thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/',
  },
  {
    original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/',
    thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/',
  },
  {
    original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/',
    thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/',
  },
];
 
class MyGallery extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ImageGallery items={images} />;
  }
}
```

However, note, I am not using the thumbnail, so I only need original.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
//import '../image-gallery.css'
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";

const AddNewItem = () => {
  var [fileState, setFile] = useState([]);

  var fileObj = {};

//bunch of irrelevant code

 //Image Preview
  const onChange = e => {

    //setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    fileObj = e.target.files[0];

    console.log("AddNewItem fileObj: ", fileObj)

    setFile(fileState => [...fileState, JSON.parse(`"orignal: ${URL.createObjectURL(fileObj)}"`)]);
}

//bunch of irrelevant code

  return (
    < Fragment >
      {console.log("AddNewItem onChange fileState: ", fileState)}

      <form id="myForm" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row ">
            <div className="col">              
             
              <label className="mt-3 mb-0">Image:</label><br />
              <input type="file" id="image" name="image" onChange={onChange}></input><br />
              <button type="submit" className="mt-3">Submit</button>

            </div>
           
            <div className="col">
              {fileState.length > 0 ? <ImageGallery items={fileState} showThumbnails={false} /> : ""}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </Fragment >
  );
```

When I upload my first image, fileState is equal to the following, and I get the Failed prop type error:

[image: Image showing array and error]

When I upload a second image, fileState looks like:

[image: Image showing fileState with 2 images]

And when there are 2 images in fileState, I do not get the error.

And no images are displayed by the gallery. I do get the arrow and play / pause button, but I do not see any images. But I am not entirely sure I have imported the image-gallery.css correctly according to the npm webpage mentioned above. But if that is an issue, then I will post another question on here.

Am I doing something wrong in the way that I am constructing fileState? If so, what can I do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an object to `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse(`{"original": "${URL.createObjectURL(fileObj)}"}`)
```

Also, you have a typo, the key should be `original`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. I am now getting an error "VM233:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 13
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)". I thing it is the b for blob.

Comment: If I add single quotes around the original value, like JSON.parse(`{"original": '${URL.createObjectURL(fileObj)}'}`), I get the opening single quote is unexpected token.

Comment: What if you use double quotes?

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me solve my problem. Looks like the CSS is right too.